# dynamically display images using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, image, dynamic

I am trying to converting this line of hard coded images into a dynamic code by using mysql to retrieve it.

```
<div class="item-block-1">
                            <span class="tag-sale"></span>
                            <div class="image-wrapper">
                                <div class="image">
                                    <div class="overlay">
                                        <div class="position">
                                            <div>
                                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis metus non erat tincidunt consectetur. Maecenas ac turpis id lorem.</p>
                                                <a href="#" class="quickshop">Quick shop</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="#"><img src="images/photos/photo-3.jpg" style="margin: -32.5px 0 0 0;" alt="" /></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <h2><a href="pandora-item.html">Polka dot light blue blouse</a></h2>
                            <p class="price">$13.99<s>$36.99</s></p>
                        </div>
```

My dynamic code is as follow but it only allows me to retrieve only one image instead of looping through the codes..

```
<div class="item-block-1">
                            <div class="image-wrapper">
                                <div class="image">
                                    <div class="overlay">
                                        <div class="position">
                                            <div>
                                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis metus non erat tincidunt consectetur. Maecenas ac turpis id lorem.</p>
                                                <a href="#" class="quickshop">Quick shop</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                         <?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_image", $connection);


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{    
   echo "<div><img src=\"uploadedimages/".$row['name']."\" /></div>"; 
}  
?> 
</div>
</div>
```

Can anyone correct me ?

Comment: first of all, you should seriously consider switching to mysqli_* or PDO, mysql_* is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0

Comment: thanks for the advice , I am still a student trying out some tutorials.. can you help me with the above?

Comment: Press `ctrl+u` and check the rendered source code in browser to check the img `src` or you can install and use `firebug` tool or developer tool in browser

Comment: @user3145668 start from here http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: you are not helping... I really need guidance..

Comment: two obvious questions: 1) did you check your result set in e.g. phpmyadmin using the query to ensure you will get more than one record?; 2) did you look at the rendered html source to ensure that it isn't merely rendering error and that you are actually only emitting a single record?

Comment: there's no error. Yes , it is supposed to get morethan one record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_image");
?>
<div class="item-block-1">
                            <div class="image-wrapper">
                                <div class="image">
                                    <div class="overlay">
                                        <div class="position">
                                            <div>
                                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis metus non erat tincidunt consectetur. Maecenas ac turpis id lorem.</p>
                                                <a href="#" class="quickshop">Quick shop</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                  <?php                                 
                                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                                       {
                                  ?>
                                   <div>
                                      <img src="new/<?php echo $row['name']; ?>"/>
                                   </div>
                                    <?php
                                       }       
                                     ?> 
                                   </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Try now. His formatting was all messed up. The `>` were not part of the code

Comment: Can you please check your database table.I have testing this code in my local system and its working perfect.

Comment: It's only showing 1 image.. It should showed 2 images . I've echo-ed the num of rows and it showed 2 as well..

Comment: Check your upload directory there will be may be only 1 image.Or if there is 2 images then there must be corrupted.run your code in Chrome because chrome always display corrupted images also as broken image.

Comment: Hi, it only displays the last image stored.. Are you able to help me on teamviewer?

Comment: yeah sure..i can help you on teamviewer.give me your skype or yahoo or gmail here.

Comment: ID : 711 659 598
PW : 8278

Answer (score 0):

Since you're up for suggestions

```
<?php
/* 
 * I usually put this in a class, but doing this all in-line for you.
 * I did this with PDO, which is just like mysql_, but better.
 */
$db_name = ''; // put your database name here
$db_host = ''; // your host name, usually localhost
$db_username = ''; // the database username used to access this database
$db_password = ''; // password associated with the username
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname='.$db_name.';host='.$db_host; // this is for the PDO object    
$PDO = new PDO($dsn, $db_username, $db_password);

$query = 'SELECT * FROM my_image';

$Stmt = $PDO->prepare($query); // prepares your SQL
$Stmt->execute() // runs your SQL

// This will test to see if you get any images back from your database
if ($Stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    /* 
     * This means you have atleast 1 image back from your database
     * The wile loop will iterate through your images from the database
     * and generate the HTML below for each, only changing the name of the file
     * on each iteration
     */
    while ($row = $Stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo '<div class="item-block-1">';
        echo     '<div class="image-wrapper">';
        echo         '<div class="image">';
        echo             '<div class="overlay">';
        echo                 '<div class="position">';
        echo                     '<div>';
        echo                         '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis metus non erat tincidunt consectetur. Maecenas ac turpis id lorem.</p>';
        echo                         '<a href="#" class="quickshop">Quick shop</a>';
        echo                     '</div>';
        echo                 '</div>'; // class="position" div   
        echo             '</div>'; // class="overlay" div   
        echo             '<div><img src="uploadedimages/'.$row['name'].'" /></div>'; // This is the actual image
        echo         '</div>'; // class="image" div    
        echo     '</div>'; // class="image-wrapper" div
        echo '</div>'; // class="image-block-1" div    

    }
}
```

Of course this is not how to properly do this, but if you were to do it in-line like this, it would be this way.  the while loop will generate the SAME html for every image, except for the image file path, which changes depending on the current row your in in the while loop.

Comment: hmm I migh have misunderstood the question.  I'll edit my answer in a bit to show adding multiple images for 1 item.  But bascially you echo the same html and loop through the images only, instead of the entire html.